# Show that $51| 10^{32n+9} - 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $51| 10^{32n+9} - 7$, use the Euler theorem to confirm that.

Euler theorem states : $a^{\phi n} \cong 1$ mod $n$.

$10^{32n+9} - 7 \cong 0$ mod $51$

$10^{32n+9} \cong 7 = 10^{32n} 10^9 = 10^{32n} 7 \cong 7 = 10^{32n} \cong 1$ mod $51$

apply Euler i got $10^{\phi (36n)} \cong 1$ mod $51$,

$10^{16\phi (n)} \cong 1$ mod $51$.

this is where i am having difficulty to see how $51| 10^{16\phi(n)}-1$when i plug some number i see that this true but still having a hard time finishing this proofs. thanks

Comment: break $51$ into $17$ and $3$ (note that $\gcd(17,3)=1$)

Comment: There seems to be something wrong, since $10^{36}\not\equiv 1\pmod{17}$

Comment: Note that $\phi(51)=\phi(17)\phi(3)=32$. Hence $10^{32}\equiv 1 \mod 51$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$51 = (3)(17)$ since gcd$(3, 17)=1$ , then i need to show that $$ 3| 10^{32n + 9} -7 $$, $$ 17| 10^{32n + 9} -7 $$

$10^{32n + 9} \cong 7 = 10^{32n} \cong 1 = 10^{16 \phi(n)} \cong 1 = 1^{16 \phi(n)} \cong 1$ mod $3$ so $3| 10^{32n + 9} -7 $

$10^{32n + 9} \cong 7 = 10^{32n} \cong 1 = 10^{16 \phi(n)}=10^{16(\phi(n))} \cong 1$ mod $17$ by fermat little theorem we have $17| 10^{32n + 9} -7 $

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(51)=\phi(17)\phi(3)=32$, hence $10^{32n} \equiv 1 \mod 51$.

Is $10^9 \equiv 7 \mod 51$? This is the remaining part.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof can be for induction:
For $n=0$, $$10^9-7\equiv 10^8\cdot 10 -7\equiv 16\cdot 10-7\equiv 0 \pmod {51}$$
Now we suppose that $$51| 10^{32n+9} - 7$$ and we demonstrate this thing for $n+1$. Therefore we have to demonstrate that $$51| 10^{32(n+1)+9} - 7$$
We have:
$$ 10^{32n+9+32} - 7= 10^{32}\cdot 10^{32n+9} - 7+7\cdot  10^{32}-7\cdot 10^{32}=10^{32}( 10^{32n+9}-7)+7\cdot 10^{32}-7 $$
Now for hypothesis we know that $51| 10^{32n+9} - 7$. Therefore we have demonstrate that $7\cdot 10^{32}-7$ is divisible for $51$. For the Eulero's theorem we know that: $10^{32}\equiv 1\pmod {51}$
Therefore $$7\cdot 10^{32}-7\equiv  0\pmod {51}$$